# ant: srcdir attribute must be non-empty

Tags: ant

**Basic Setup**

Ant newbie; Mac OS

**What I am trying to do**

https://github.com/MIT-DB-Class/course-info-2017/blob/master/lab1.md#1-getting-started.

**Commands I use**

- git clone git@github.com:MIT-DB-Class/simple-db-hw.git
- cd simple-db-hw
- brew install ant
- ant test

**What I get after the last command**

---

> Buildfile: /Users/evan/Desktop/tmp1/simple-db-hw/build.xml
>
> compile:
>
> BUILD FAILED /Users/evan/Desktop/tmp1/simple-db-hw/build.xml:169: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /Users/evan/Desktop/tmp1/simple-db-hw/build.xml:46:
>   /Users/evan/Desktop/tmp1/simple-db-hw/build.xml:46: srcdir attribute
>   must be non-empty
>
> Total time: 0 seconds

---

**Related file**

Here are the build.xml: https://gist.github.com/YikSanChan/9ce29ec239db525cd9d4bd62baa62095

**Things I have tried**

The issue with `homebrew install ant`? I tried to download 1.10.2.tar.gz from http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi and gets the same result.

**Question**

What's wrong? Any advice is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `Compile` macrodef. It tries to reference the attribute named `srcdir` but it is written as a standard property reference using the `${}` syntax, instead of the attribute syntax which uses `@{}`.

So on line 46 try changing this:

```
<macrodef name="Compile">
    <attribute name="srcdir"/>
    <attribute name="destdir"/>
    <element name="compileoptions" implicit="true" optional="true"/>
    <sequential>
        <mkdir dir="@{destdir}"/>
        <!-- avoids needing ant clean when changing interfaces -->
        <depend srcdir="${srcdir}" destdir="${destdir}" cache="${depcache}"/>
        <javac srcdir="@{srcdir}" destdir="@{destdir}" includeAntRuntime="no"
                debug="${compile.debug}" source="${sourceversion}">
            <compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked" />
            <!--<compilerarg value="-Xlint:deprecation" />-->
            <compileoptions/>
        </javac>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

into this:

```
<macrodef name="Compile">
    <attribute name="srcdir"/>
    <attribute name="destdir"/>
    <element name="compileoptions" implicit="true" optional="true"/>
    <sequential>
        <mkdir dir="@{destdir}"/>
        <!-- avoids needing ant clean when changing interfaces -->
        <depend srcdir="@{srcdir}" destdir="@{destdir}" cache="${depcache}"/>
        <javac srcdir="@{srcdir}" destdir="@{destdir}" includeAntRuntime="no"
                debug="${compile.debug}" source="${sourceversion}">
            <compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked" />
            <!--<compilerarg value="-Xlint:deprecation" />-->
            <compileoptions/>
        </javac>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Also note that `destdir` should be changed in the same way as well.

Comment: The `src` directory was actually missing.